# How can I modify a Vuetify sass variable for a specific instance of a component?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a sample codepen at https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/gORvzdG

For the first instance of the treeview, I would like to use a treeview-node-level-width of 8px. The second instance of the treeview should remain unchanged.

How can I target a particular treeview instance and modify the value of the variable?

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Documents :',
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'vuetify :',
            children: [
              {
                id: 7,
                name: 'src :',
                children: [
                  { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
    <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to overwrite the sass variable in this case, just the target class on the specific instance.

```js
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview class="narrow" :items="items"></v-treeview>
    <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>

<style>
.narrow .v-treeview-node__level {
  width: 8px !important;
}
</style>
```